# Redirect subfolder to index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I want, when the user browses to

```
https://example.com/test/admin
```

or

```
https://example.com/test/admin/
```

that it redirects to the corresponding index.php file like this:

```
https://example.com/test/admin/index.php
```

But still shows only the folder name in the URL like this:

```
https://example.com/test/admin/
```

---

I know that you can use htaccess in some way and I've tried searching for answers but all the answers are really old and I have no idea what they do and there doesn't seem to be one that just wants this specific behaviour and nothing more.

Comment: Add `DirectoryIndex index.php` at top of .htaccess

Comment: @anubhava thank you very, very much!

Comment: And a general hint: instead of searching through countless snippets and answers it usually is _much_ more effective to take a look at the documentation of the tools you use.